# C++ Type Conversion to component - preserving string properties

Tags: c#, ios, bluetooth, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building a Xamarin.Forms app and am using the [Monkey.Robotics](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) plug-in. I have a `ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;` line, collecting the results from a device scan. I want to present these in a cross platform choice Pop Up, as explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/). The code below is where I am currently at, but I am having type conversion issues.

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Choose Your Device", "Can't see It?", null, this.devices.Select(device => device.Name).ToArray());
                if (action == "Can't see It?"){
                                      //show help prompt
                };
var device = action as IDevice; //pass this as device to the service routines...
```

I get an error on the last line, **cannot convert type 'String' to 'Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.IDevice' via a built in conversion** Is there a way I can manually perform that conversion, only on the output, whilst still letting the DisplayAction inputs keep in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to convert a `string` to an implementation of `IDevice` as `String` does not implement `IDevice`! I think what you need to do is select the correct device object based on the name coming back:

```
var device = this.devices.Single(device => device.Name == action);
```